# How do I rotate a polynomial algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rigid-transformation

How do I algebraically rotate a polynomial 90 degrees CW (clockwise) or CCW (counterclockwise) in the $xy$ plane?

For example, rotate $f(x) = x^2$ clockwise $90$ degrees. I understand that a CW rotation of 90 degrees takes a point $(x,y)$ to a point $(y,-x)$, but when I substitute and simplify this, I get $-x = y^2$, then $y = \pm \sqrt{-x}$. I know it should be $y = \pm \sqrt{x}$ and I don't understand how it rotated backwards. I teach algebra II to high schoolers and they do not yet know radians or parametric equations, so I would like a simple explanation if at all possible. Thank you!

Comment: I know you mentioned your students don't know parametric equations, but perhaps this will help you obtain the desired formula. A coordinate pair on the parabola is $(t,t^2)$. Applying your transformation to this pair gives $(t^2,-t)$. So now we have that $x=t^2$ and $y=-t$. We can solve for $t$ using the first equation: $t=\pm\sqrt{x}$. Now we can substitute this into $y=-t = -(\pm\sqrt{x}) = \pm\sqrt{x}$. So overall, $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$ as you wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: There is a difference between rotating the plane, and rotating the coordinate grid that you've put on top of the plane. Moving one of them one way yields the same effect as moving the other the exact opposite way.

It's the same reason that $f(x-5)$ moves the graph of $f$ five units to the *right* compared to $f(x)$, when subtracting ought to move things to the *left*: it actually moves the coordinate grid to the left, keeping the graph in place. But you don't see that, as the coordinate grid is your only point of reference.

Comment: In this case, since the graph is symmetric about an axis, you could consider reflecting it about a $45^\circ$ diagonal rather than rotating it. In that case it should be much easier to get it right, as it doesn't matter whether you reflect the coordinate system or the plane; the resulting picture is the same either way.

Comment: I find it easiest to understand via this suggestion of considering a second coordinate grid, but until you get realllly experienced with it (i.e. no longer in high school) it's very important to use different variables for the second grid, like $(x', y')$. Then you figure out how $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$ are related, put $x$ and $y$ in terms $x'$ and $y$', plug those into your equation for $(x.y)$, and that's how you get your equation for $(x',y')$. It's the best way I've found to understand the $f(x-5)$ phenomenon Arthur describes.

Comment: And once you're done with all that one can remove the primes from the final equation, to make things look simpler, but it does risk confusion. As a teacher that's the kind of thing that I'd let my students slide on but would try to be fastidious about keeping the renamed coordinates when I wrote things up myself.